Когда раскрывается макрос "__FILE__"?
Я делаю в хедере lib.h
#define TEST __FILE__

а потом в main.cpp:
#include "lib.h"
std::cout << TEST;

И мне печатает имя main.cpp. Я бы ожидал файл lib.h. В каком порядке раскрываются инклюды и прочие макросы?

Макрос раскрывается в имя компилируемого файла. У вас таковой — main.cpp. Ну, а порядок... препроцессор обрабатывает все #include, потом раскрывает все макросы. Макрос раскрывается там, где он используется, а не где определяется.

Макросы раскрываются в момент подстановки. Если бы вы использовали макрос внутри lib.h, вы бы получили ожидаемое.

А когда происходит подстановка? То есть почему include сразу же подставляется, а file "ждёт" пока не заюзается

Попробуйте в lib.h написать типа const char * с = TEST;, а потом вывести.

Тогда так как ожидаю будет. Но мне бы раз и навсегда понять механизм пошагово как происходит. То есть мы идём, видим include, идём по хедеру, видим #define и не раскрываем, а ждём использования?

В С/C++ используется простой текстовый препроцессор, производящий подстановку кусков текста. Содержимое исходных файлов для него делится на две категории:

Директивы препроцессора - строки с # и до неэкроноированного символа переноса строки. Встречая эти директивы, препроцессор их обрабатывает, модифицируя свое поведение и заменяет. В случае с #include директива будет заменена на содержимое соотв. файла. В случае с #define (и большинством прочих директив) директива заменяется на на пустую строку.
Тест программы - все, что не является директивами препроцессора. При обработке текста программы при встрече известного препроцессору токена он заменят этот токен на токены для подстановки. Затем заново обрабатывает текст программы начиная с токлько что подставленных токенов. И повторяет этот процесс, пока в тексте программы больше не останется токенов для замены.

Таким образом, встретив в коде из вопроса:

Препроцессор заменяет директиву #include "lib.h" содержимым файла.
Обрабатывая только что вставленный из заголовочного файла текст, натыкается на директиву #define TEST __FILE__
Запоминает, что при встрече в тексте программы токена TEST его надо будет заменить на токен __FILE__, и заменяет директиву на пустую строку.
Натыкается на токен TEST в тексте main.cpp.
Заменяет TEST на __FILE__ по запомненному ранее правилу.
Обрабатывая только то вставленный текст, натыкается на токен __FILE__.
Заменяет __FILE__ на строковый литерал с именем файла, в котором сейчас происходит подстановка, то бишь на "main.cpp".


Супер, теперь точно понятно!

Макросы раскрываются в момент подстановки. Если бы вы использовали макрос внутри lib.h, вы бы получили ожидаемое:

$ cat temp.h
#define TEST __FILE__

void f() {
    puts(TEST);
}

$ cat temp.c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <temp.h>

void g() {
    puts(TEST);
}

int main() {
    f();
    g();
}

$ gcc -I. temp.c

$ ./a.out
./temp.h
temp.c



#define TEST __FILE__ не считается подстановкой когда мы анализируем хедер? Что считается подстановкой?

Нет. Это определение препроцессора. Он их запоминает. Подстановка возникает в момент использования макроса.

Окей, то есть #define и #undef запоминаются и раскроются только в моменте использования, а всё остальное сразу же?

#define сразу сохраняет определение но ничего не вычисляет. #undef сразу удаляет определение, но ничего не вычисляет. #if/#ifdef/#ifndef сразу включают или исключают блоки кода, они вычисляют свои аргументы. Использование макроса в коде приводит к его вычислению. Препроцессор настолько ленив, насколько это возможно.
